# Como imprimir pdf desde python sin adobe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo el siguiente script de python el cual forma parte de un producto que estoy desarrollando (está reducido para que puedan reproducirlo) usa **win32print** para mandar a imprimir un pdf y funciona bien. El problema es que al hacerlo abre adobe **acrobat pdf** para mandar a imprimir y en las computadoras de algunos clientes, adobe se crashea. Es posible modificarlo para que no requiera abrir  ningún software externo? Hice algunos intentos con **ghostcript** pero no lo puede importar según la terminal porque faltan archivos. Me metí en un agujero de conejo sólo para salir más confundido y sin saber si podría correr el software después en las pcs de los clientes.
Me disculpo por tanto texto y les dejo el script abajo:

```
        output_path=r"C:\Users\PC\Documents\recibo34.pdf"
        
        
        default_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
        win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", output_path, '/d:{}'.format(default_printer), ".", 0)
```

Comment: El mundo de imprimir en python es complicado, con poca información. Incluso si tu código funcionase, serviría unicamente en Windows, la mejor y casi unica solución que encontré, siendo overkill, es recurrir a Qt (una librería de gui para c) a traves de sus bindings en Python (pyqt y pyside) que ofrece un sistema de impresión multiplataforma facil de usar.

Comment: Si aún querés una solución usando la api de windows, hace tiempo hice un código que publiqué en otro sitio de stack exchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/273338/254509

Comment: @DanteS. Hola Dante, al final decidí usar gsprint porque ahora sé que funciona en cualquier windows64 y en venezuela nuestros clientes no usan otra cosa. Le dí una revisada a tu código y no voy a mentir, me quedó grande. Pero igual gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Hola y gracias a los que contestaron. Al final pude aplicar **gsprint** y la verdad es que no creo que haya problemas con las computadoras de los clientes. Tuve que darle la vuelta a internet para estar seguro. En fin, abajo dejo cómo quedó el bloque de código a utilizar.

```
import os
import win32print # pip install win32printing
import win32api # pip install win-api

currentprinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
print(currentprinter)
gspath = r"D:\gs\gs10021w64.exe"
gsp_path = r"D:\gs\gsprint.exe"


path = r"C:\Users\PC\Documents\recibo34.pdf"
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', gsp_path, '-ghostscript "'+gspath+'" -printer "'+currentprinter+'" "%s"'%(path), '.', 0)
```

Comment: Perfecto. Solo recuerda decirles a tus clientes que tu programa funciona solo en windows.